# Search engine for python on shared hosting

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, whoosh

I'm currently in the process of building a website in which the user can query a book name and get a result from a mysql database of around 30,000 books.

I've finished building the database and now i'm looking for a good search engine implementation for python. Initially i though of using Elasticsearch, but i currently have a very limited budget so i can only purchase shared web hosting and i read that Elasticsearch is too demanding for a shared hosting server.

I also read I can use Haystack + Whoosh since im using Django, but I've also read whoosh is quite slow.

What do you think I should use to supply the website quick and accurate search functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you searching? If it's just book titles, MySQL is perfectly capable of doing that already.

Comment: Yes I'm only interested in searching the book titles, but the thing is that the search feature is pretty much the main thing about the website, so i want to make as fast and accurate as possible and perhaps have a score reflecting the result relevance which as far as i know mysql isnt capable of, am i wrong?